# Automatically close window after some time

Tags: php, javascript

I want to close a window automatically after 5 minutes. I've tried with both PHP and Javascript. But the problem is when the pop up window reloads, the counter is start from 0 again. In short, I want to close the pop up window after 5 minutes, still when it reloads.

Comment: show us some code :D - Preferably the part with the timer and the one that does the closing

Comment: you will have to pass the time passed as a GET or POST parameter if page gets reloaded

Comment: Use an `<iframe>`, so that the main page stays persistent with the JavaScript and the iframe can reload safely.

Comment: Or store a cookie with the time in miliseconds of when the page was first loaded.

Comment: Or set the time in a session variable

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("window.close();", 3000);</script>`

Answer (score 0):

using javascript call the following function on window load:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.close(); }, 300000);
```

Comment: But that won't work on refresh because the timeout would be disposed and set again.

Comment: Ok, youre right, then the best way would be saving the remaining time server side, and querying it via Ajax from time to time.

Comment: how to do that using extJS 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = window.open('/advertise.html', 'blah', 'width=400, height=300');

foo.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    foo.opener.setTimeout(function() {
        foo.close();
    }, 5000);
}, false);
```

That should actually work. This won't work if the popup loads a page from a different domain obv.

Comment: Why copy the window object? And why parent?

Comment: @mplungjan: I just realized it,  should be `opener` instead. Copying the window object just for convinience.

Comment: @jAndy - so we just need to close the parent window and the timeout goes away. Also you need to ask if (foo && !foo.closed())

Comment: @mplungjan: no clue what you're talking about, if we close the parent window, the popup will close aswell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an opener window will close all opened "child" windows when it's get closed.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Wishful thinking

Comment: @mplungjan: can you proove that?

Comment: http://plungjan.name/test/testopenclose.html - if you allow popups, it will not close child window in neither Fx4 nor IE8 on Windows Xp when the parent closes

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - please notice that you can only close a window you opened using script

```
<?PHP
 // set this on session start
 $sessionStartTimeString = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
?>
window.onload=function() {
  var serverTime = new Date('<?php echo $sessionStartTimeString ;?>');
  var nowTime = new Date('<?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i a");?>');
  var closeTime = serverTime.setMinutes(serverTime.getMinutes()+5);
  var diff = closeTime.getTime()-nowTime.getTime();
  if (diff > 0) setTimeout(function() { window.close(); }, diff);
  else window.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "nice way" but if your page have to reload you can set and store a time on which to close the popup inside a cookie. If the cookie is already set just launch the timer (an interval that check time isn't passed ?), if not already present set it to a time in 5 minutes and finally delete it when closing the popup.

Comment: Tutorial that makes using cookies very very easy. (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Comment: I would prefer a cookie over a session variable, doing so allow to be independant of the server, allowing to re-use the script within a non php application